# knapsack pseudopolynomial time algorightm

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am learning about Knapsack (0/1) problem.
The solution has a running time of NW where N is the number of items and W is the total weight permitted to carry.

Why then is the solution is called as pseudopolynomial time  algorithm ?

I read one argument from (http://www.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1138/lectures/20/Small20.pdf)

The solution talks about bits required to write out the input W
how is the bits required to write out the bits (log W) ?

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is polynomial in the *values* of its inputs. However, the storage size of a number, represented in an ordinary way (e.g. base 2), is `log(number)`, making the algorithm exponential time in the *size* of the input. O() notation is usually concerned with input size, not value, so a pseudopolynomial algorithm cannot be considered polynomial-time.

This matters because you can feed the algorithm just two 1KB numbers, and it will take millennia to finish. In contrast, a real polynomial-time algorithm would scale polynomially with the physical size of its inputs: for example, a computer could multiply the 1KB numbers in a matter of milliseconds.